# Improve JavaFX gradient

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I want to improve the css background with the gradient:

```
scroll.setStyle("-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FAFAFA, #EAEAEA);");
```

But I see tiny slices into the background color. The quality of the gradient is not so good. Can I somehow improve the gradient quality?

Comment: I can't replicate this, to my eyes the gradient `linear-gradient(to bottom, #FAFAFA, #EAEAEA)` is [smooth on my system](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xiV6z.png).  Test system: Java 8b101, OS X 10.8.4.